# Is there any way to make a switch statement out of this mess of if else if?

Tags: c#, algorithm

Is there an easier way to do this without bringing in a bunch of mathematics? Perhaps maybe a switch statement?

```
            if (myChoice == "Rock" && compChoice == "Scissors")
            {
                winner = "player";
                win++;
            }

            else if (myChoice == "Rock" && compChoice == "Lizard")
            {
                winner = "player";
                win++;
            }

            else if (myChoice == "Paper" && compChoice == "Rock")
            {
                winner = "player";
                win++;
            }

            else if (myChoice == "Paper" && compChoice == "Spock")
            {
                winner = "player";
                win++;
            }

            else if (myChoice == "Scissors" && compChoice == "Paper")
            {
                winner = "player";
                win++;
            }

            else if (myChoice == "Scissors" && compChoice == "Lizard")
            {
                winner = "player";
                win++;
            }

            else if (myChoice == "Lizard" && compChoice == "Spock")
            {
                winner = "player";
                win++;
            }

            else if (myChoice == "Lizard" && compChoice == "Paper")
            {
                winner = "player";
                win++;
            }

            else if (myChoice == "Spock" && compChoice == "Scissors")
            {
                winner = "player";
                win++;
            }

            else if (myChoice == "Spock" && compChoice == "Rock")
            {
                winner = "player";
                win++;
            }

            else if (compChoice == "Rock" && myChoice == "Scissors")
            {
                winner = "computer";
                lose++;
            }

            else if (compChoice == "Rock" && myChoice == "Lizard")
            {
                winner = "computer";
                lose++;
            }

            else if (compChoice == "Paper" && myChoice == "Rock")
            {
                winner = "computer";
                lose++;
            }

            else if (compChoice == "Paper" && myChoice == "Spock")
            {
                winner = "computer";
                lose++;
            }

            else if (compChoice == "Scissors" && myChoice == "Paper")
            {
                winner = "computer";
                lose++;
            }

            else if (compChoice == "Scissors" && myChoice == "Lizard")
            {
                winner = "computer";
                lose++;
            }

            else if (compChoice == "Lizard" && myChoice == "Spock")
            {
                winner = "computer";
                lose++;
            }

            else if (compChoice == "Lizard" && myChoice == "Paper")
            {
                winner = "computer";
                lose++;
            }

            else if (compChoice == "Spock" && myChoice == "Scissors")
            {
                winner = "computer";
                lose++;
            }

            else if (compChoice == "Spock" && myChoice == "Rock")
            {
                winner = "computer";
                lose++;
            }

            else
            {
                winner = "none";
                tie++;
            }
```

I played around with this for a little while but looking for an easier way to show some friends that are learning c#. I'm quite the beginner myself so I wasn't able to offer anymore assistance. I'm hoping that someone on here can point us in the right direction. Thanks in advance for any advice you can offer.

Comment: Use a 2D table of possible results (where each result is an enum expressing "player wins", "opponent wins" and "draw") for each possible combination. Then you can just use the player choice (row number) and the opponent choice (column number) to index into the correct result for that combination.

Comment: Also another thing to consider is the use of `||` (OR), so you can do `if (winCond1 || winCond2 || winCond3...) { win }` and write `win` only once

Comment: You can switch on a tuple, but it would not look much different: `switch (myChoice, compChoice) { case ("Rock", "Paper"): winner = "Player"; win++; break;` ...etc

Comment: It's not good to make every variable a string.  `enum Player { None, Human, Computer }` then `winner = Player.Human;` is both faster for a computer than working on strings, and also the compiler will check that you used one of the three legal values, no accidental "plyer" or "n0ne" mixed in.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  This looks good.  everyone has presented great options that I have passed on. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good candidate for a switch expression, if your compiler is new enough to support it:

```
winner = myChoice switch
{
     "Rock" => compChoice switch
     {
          "Rock" => "none",
          "Scissors" or "Lizard" => "player",
          "Paper" or "Spock" => "computer"
     },
     "Scissors" => compChoice switch
     {
          "Scissors" => "none",
          "Paper" or "Lizard" => "player",
          "Rock" or "Spock" => "computer"
     }
     // and so on
}
```

Naturally this also works with proper `enum` variables.

But this is still redundant, as you have to have anti-symmetric entries.  We can take advantage of that:

```
bool beats(string first, string second)
   => first switch
      {
          "Rock" => second is "Scissors" or "Lizard",
          "Scissors" => second is "Paper" or "Lizard",
          "Paper" => second is "Rock" or "Spock",
          "Lizard" => second is "Paper" or "Spock",
          "Spock" => second is "Rock" or "Scissors"
      };

 bool playerWins = beats(playerChoice, compChoice);
 bool computerWins = beats(compChoice, playerChoice);
 switch ((playerWins, computerWins)) {
     case (true, false):
         winner = "player";
         wins++;
         break;
     case (false, true):
         winner = "computer";
         loss++;
         break;
     case (false, false):
         winner = "none";
         draw++;
         break;
     case (true, true):
         MessageBox.Show("Problem with the rules!");
         break;
 }
```

This is competitive with a lookup table for code length and probably more readable.  And it checks the consistency of the rules, you can't accidentally make player "Rock" beat computer "Paper" at the same time that player "Paper" beats computer "Rock".

Answer (score 0):

I'd get rid of as many of those strings as possible. Here's what you could do with a couple `enum`s and a supporting class to play a round of the game.

```
public enum Choice
{
    Rock, Paper, Scissors, Spock, Lizard
}

public enum Result
{
    Win, Lose, Draw
}

public static class Roshambo
{
    // This is a lookup table of the choice against what it beats.
    private static readonly Dictionary<Choice, List<Choice>> Any = new()
    {
        {Choice.Rock, new() {Choice.Scissors, Choice.Lizard}},
        {Choice.Paper, new() {Choice.Rock, Choice.Spock}},
        {Choice.Scissors, new() {Choice.Paper, Choice.Lizard}},
        {Choice.Lizard, new() {Choice.Spock, Choice.Paper}},
        {Choice.Spock, new() {Choice.Scissors, Choice.Rock}}
    };

    public static Result Play(Choice one, Choice theOther)
    {
        if (one == theOther) return Result.Draw;
        return Any[one].Contains(theOther) 
            ? Result.Win 
            : Result.Lose;
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = Roshambo.Play(Choice.Scissors, Choice.Rock);
    // Here you could switch over the result
    Console.WriteLine(result); // Lose
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.  I had tried this, but was having trouble getting it set up correctly myself.   Everyone has presented great options that I have passed on. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

If we have all states as

```
static List<string> states = new List<string> {
  "Scissors", "Paper", "Rock", "Lizzard", "Spock"
};
```

the rules will be simple:

> `A` wins `B` if and only if either `indexB - indexB == 1` or `indexB - indexA == 2`.

> E.g. **Rock** wins **Scissors** and **Lizzard**

Note, however, that we should compute *circular* differencies (`-1 ~ 4`, `-2 ~ 3`, `-3 ~ -2` etc.), e.g. `Spock` wins `Scissors`; me can do it with a help of *modulo arithmetics*:

```
private static bool FirstWins(string first, string second) {
  int difference = (states.IndexOf(first) - states.IndexOf(second) + states.Count) 
     % states.Count;

  return difference == 2 || difference == states.Count - 1; 
}
```

Finally

```
static string Winner(string user, string computer) =>
    FirstWins(user, computer) ? "User"
  : FirstWins(computer, user) ? "Computer"
  : "Draw";
```

Comment: You have a modulo (`%`) in your code but not in your description of the solution.